# Where are accounts and smart contracts stored?

Tags: smart-contract, accounts, ram, ram-allocation

I'm a bit confused by answers to the following questions:

[Where are new accounts stored?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/3295/where-are-new-accounts-stored)

[Where is the smart contract is stored](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/5366/where-is-the-smart-contract-is-stored)

How can everything be stored on RAM at all time? 3KB for each user means we can only have 21M users? set aside the space needed for smart contracts